# Any vertical cover flow slider like attached?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, slider, coverflow

[image: attached slider screenshot. not find any javascript, jquery or vueJs slider like this.]

attached slider screenshot. not find any javascript, jquery or vueJs slider like this.

Comment: Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

[Vue Carousel 3D](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/) seems like it may be configurable-enough to give you what you need.

Go to [the Playground section](https://wlada.github.io/vue-carousel-3d/playground/) and use the following options:

- Slide space: 30
- Slide width: 360
- Slide height: 270
- Slide border: 1
- Slide perspective: 0
- Slide scaling: 10

[image]

You should end up with something that looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Not found any option to make it vertical any other idea?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show the options I used to create something like the picture in your question.